# Multivariable do repeat command SPSS

Tags: loops, repeat, spss

I am trying to combine two variables into a char.index test. The following code works for looping through the variables with a static string to find. PR1 to PR25 are variables in the dataset. This code puts a "1" in the new variable, test, if "02703" is found in at least one of the searched variables.

```
Compute test=0.
DO REPEAT  haystack = PR1 to PR25. 
   IF CHAR.INDEX(haystack,"02703")>0 test=1.
END REPEAT.
EXECUTE.
```

In place of the "02703", I would like to loop through a list of strings: "027034" "027035" "027036" "027037" "02703D" "02703E" "02703F"

Tried the follow code (not working)

```
Compute test=0.
Loop haystacks = PR1 to PR25. 
DO REPEAT  needles="027034" "027035" "027036" "027037" "02703D" "02703E" "02703F".
-      IF CHAR.INDEX(haystacks,needles)>0 test=1.
END REPEAT.
END LOOP.
EXECUTE.
```

Also not working

```
Compute test=0.
DO REPEAT  haystacks = PR1 to PR25/ needles="027034" "027035" "027036" "027037" "02703D" "02703E" "02703F".
-      IF CHAR.INDEX(haystacks,needles)>0 test=1.
END REPEAT.
EXECUTE.
```

I am using char.index as the needles are only part of the string. For example, 027034 should match 0270346 and 027034Z.

Is it possible to combine two do repeat variables into one computation? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`DO REPEAT` does not work inside a `loop`
The easiest way out for you would be to use several `IF` inside a `DO REPEAT`, one `IF` for each needle:

```
Compute test=0.
DO REPEAT  haystack = PR1 to PR25. 
   IF CHAR.INDEX(haystack,"02703")>0 test=1.
   IF CHAR.INDEX(haystack,"02704")>0 test=1.
   IF CHAR.INDEX(haystack,"02705")>0 test=1.
   ...
   ...
END REPEAT.
EXECUTE.
```

One note regard loops: they work best with `VECTOR` command, and allow for nested structures (which `DO REPEAT` *does not allow*). If you have your needles stored as variables (well, SPSS variables, but otherwise with *constant* values), you could try `VECTOR` with nested `loop` approach. But it would be a little counter-intuitive, in my opinion, and I only mentioned it to point out the differences between `DO REPEAT` and `LOOP`.